# unexpected token in HQL

Tags: hibernate

This is my HQL quey.But this is executed,the following error occurred.How we can solve this problem

error:unexpected token: d1

```
select d from DimensionStone d inner join d.stockRegister s where d.stockRegister.stockRegisterId <=? and s.application.applicationId=? 
    and d.isIssued='No' or (s.stockRegisterId <=? and d.isIssued='Yes' and d.issuedDate>(select max(updatedOn) from StockRegister st where st.stockRegisterId<? and st.application.applicationId=?)) and d not in(select d1 from DimensionStone d1 inner join d1.stockRegister s1 where s1.stockRegisterId <=? and s1.application.applicationId=? d1.isIssued='No'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `and` between `s1.application.applicationId=?` and `d1.isIssued='No'`.

```
select d from DimensionStone d inner join d.stockRegister s where d.stockRegister.stockRegisterId <=? and s.application.applicationId=? 
and d.isIssued='No' or (s.stockRegisterId <=? and d.isIssued='Yes' and d.issuedDate>(select max(updatedOn) from StockRegister st where st.stockRegisterId<? and st.application.applicationId=?)) and d not in(select d1 from DimensionStone d1 inner join d1.stockRegister s1 where s1.stockRegisterId <=? and s1.application.applicationId=? 
and d1.isIssued='No'
```

Comment: Hello,one more question is can I use EXCEPT clause in hql

Answer (score 0):

```
and s1.application.applicationId=? d1.isIssued='No'
```

You are missing something between `?` and `d1`, probably `and`.

Comment: Hello,one more question is can I use EXCEPT clause in hql